# C# Activator.CreateInstance MissingMethod exception

Tags: c#, activator

I'm trying to create instances of objects that have the same base type like this:

```
  Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  var objs = myAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(SearchLogicObjectBase)).OrderBy(o => o.FullName);

  foreach (var item in objs)
  {
    SearchLogicObjectBase p = (SearchLogicObjectBase)Activator.CreateInstance(item.GetType(), new Object[] { false });        
    _searchlogic.AddDefaultSearchObject(p);
  }
```

The derived objects have constructors like this:

```
public SearchLogicCsri()
  : this(true)
{ }

public SearchLogicCsri(bool extendsearch)
  : base(extendsearch)
{
  Table = "csri";
  ViewModel = "CsriViewModel";
  ExtendSearch = extendsearch;
}
```

and the base object (SearchLogicObjectBase) has a constructor like this:

```
public SearchLogicObjectBase(bool extendsearch)
{
  _extendsearch = extendsearch;
}
```

However, the above code results in the following exception:

Constructor on type 'System.RuntimeType' not found.

Both the base and derived types have a constructor that takes a single boolean so I'm not sure why I get the error.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not pass item.GetType() but item, since item is already a type.